# How to get the cause of an error in React's ErrorBoundary

Tags: reactjs

In ErrorBoundary, I want to get the cause of the error.

For example, the following component raises the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null".

I want to catch this message in the ErrorBoundary and log it.
However, I can get a stack trace of the component, but I can't get such an error.

Is there a better way to do it?

Component:

```
const BugComponent = () => {
    // set Null
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

    // "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null"
    return (<p>{value.foo}</p>);
}


ReactDOM.render(<ErrorBoundary><BugComponent /></ErrorBoundary>, el);
```

ErrorBoundary.jsx:

```
export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null};
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
        this.setState({
            error: error,
            errorInfo: errorInfo,
        });

        // I want this error message.
        // "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null"

    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.errorInfo) {
            // Error path
            return (
                <p>Error occured.</p>
            );
        }
        // Normally, just render children
        return this.props.children;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `ErrorBoundary` from form react library, it released in react 16,
Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed. Error boundaries catch errors during rendering, in lifecycle methods, and in constructors of the whole tree below them.

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    logErrorToMyService(error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as a regular component:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <Child />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Error boundaries work like a JavaScript `catch {}` block, but for components. Only class components can be error boundaries. In practice, most of the time you’ll want to declare an error boundary component once and use it throughout your application.